# Limit filling out a form for an instance of User to once a day (Django)

Tags: python, django

I'm working on this web app that let people sign in, and be able to create: users, create beers and reviews for the different types of beers.

This is my models.py for creating a beer:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

# Models

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class BeerModel(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, default="")
    style = models.CharField(max_length=254, default="")
    ibu = models.IntegerField(default="")
    calories = models.IntegerField(default="")
    abv = models.IntegerField(default="")
    location = models.CharField(max_length=254, default="")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Beers'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def avg(self):
        return
```

This is my forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import BeerModel, RateModel

# Forms

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')
        help_texts = {
            'username': None,
        }

class NewBeerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(label="Beer Name")
    ibu = forms.IntegerField(label="IBU")
    abv = forms.IntegerField(label="ABV")
    location = forms.CharField(label="Brewery Location")

    class Meta:
        model = BeerModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

And this is my views.py:

```
@login_required
def new_beer(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        beer = NewBeerForm(request.POST)
        if beer.is_valid():
            beer.save(commit=True)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('beer_tracker:home'))
    else:
        beer = NewBeerForm()

    return render(request, 'beer_tracker/new_beer.html', {'beer':beer})
```

As you can see, to create a beer, you need to fill out a couple of details including the "User" field.

So my goal is to be able to limit that specific User that I chose to be able to create one beer per day only.

Any thoughts? I was looking into celery, but I'm sure there is a much better way.

Anthony

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to add a datetime field to store when the beer was created.

```
class BeerModel(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, default="")
    style = models.CharField(max_length=254, default="")
    ibu = models.IntegerField(default="")
    calories = models.IntegerField(default="")
    abv = models.IntegerField(default="")
    location = models.CharField(max_length=254, default="")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Then you will have to update your view to check if there is a beer that was created within one day.

```
from django.utils import timezone


@login_required
def new_beer(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        yesterday = timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(days=1)
        if BeerModel.objects.filter(user=request.user, created__gt=yesterday).exists():
            return HttpResponseForbidden()   # return a 403 status code
        beer = NewBeerForm(request.POST)
        if beer.is_valid():
            beer.save(commit=True)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('beer_tracker:home'))
    else:
        beer = NewBeerForm()

    return render(request, 'beer_tracker/new_beer.html', {'beer':beer})
```

Comment: First of all, Thank you so much for your help. I tried this, but it sorta kinda of work. The problem is that it lets me create a beer once per day for "All users" instead of just for that specific user. Any thoughts?

Comment: by "that specific user" do you mean the currently logged in user?

Comment: No. I will clarify. When creating a beer, there is a field that lets you select the user, from the list of users that have been created, that then is assigned to that specific beer. The reason I built this is so when I create a beer, I can tell who likes that beer. So, I'm not limiting the user that is logged in to create a beer once a day, I'm limiting the User i select.

Comment: I got it working as you suggested. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

The first thing you will have to do is create a `DateField` in `BeerModel`:

```
class BeerModel(models.Model):
    ...
    created = models.DateField(default=django.utils.timezone.now)
    # or (but see https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20180)
    # created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Then, if you want to enforce this at the database level, you can create a `unique_together` constraint:

```
class BeerModel(models.Model):
    ...
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'created')
```

Or you could just have a `clean` method on the form to check this:

```
class NewBeerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean() 
        user = cleaned_data.get('user')
        created = datetime.now().date()           
        if BeerModel.objects.filter(user=user, created=created).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("User already created beer today")
```

You will probably always need the `clean` anyway, because of the ticket I mentioned above (if it still applies). If you use an editable field for the date, you have to make sure the current day is saved to the database. E.g:

```
if beer.is_valid():
    instance = beer.save(commit=False)
    instance.created = datetime.now().date()
    instance.save()
```